# How to use Python and BeautifulSoup to parse classes

Tags: html, python-3.x, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse only the independent claims off of google.com/patents, but they use the same class name as the children dependent claims. I am new, but I think what I am trying to ask is how do I exclude child results if the parent has a particular class name.

I have tried to work the examples of *parent / child / sibling / etc*. off of [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree) BeautifulSoup tutorial.

Unfortunately, nothing seemed to work.

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/US7054130?oq=US7654309'

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')


claims = soup.find_all('div', class_='claim')

for claim in claims:

    if claim.find(class_='claim-dependent style-scope patent-text'):
        continue
    print(claim.text)
```

I expected the dependent claim sections to be skipped and only the independent claims printed.

Results - All the claims, independent and dependent, gets printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statement does not do anything, because it contains just `continue` (and the result is empty by the way), so you are printing all claims in the next line.

You could filter all the claims with the dependent `claim-ref` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/US7054130?oq=US7654309'

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')


claims = soup.find_all('div', class_='claim')

for claim in claims:
    if not claim.find('claim-ref'):
        print(claim.find(class_='claim'))
```

Comment: I am a new to this and a little uncertain where the 'claim-ref' came from. Does it refer to 'claim-dependent' where ref takes the place of 'dependent'?

Comment: Every child (dependent cliam) has a `<claim-ref>` tag, which is referencing one parent, e.g. `<claim-ref idref="CLM-00001">claim 1</claim-ref>`. I am filtering such all claims, that have such a tag, so that only independent claims remain. 
Also please consider accepting or upvoting m solution if it helped you or you liked it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Simply filter on parent and child classes I think as this excludes claims with parent class of `claim-dependent` which I assume are the dependants.

```
print(soup.select('.claim .claim')
```

3 matches (claims 1,6,19)

---

You can see one of each type here:

[image]

This is for claims 1 and 2. The top, claim 1, has parent div with class `claim` and child with class `claim`, whereas the bottom, claim 2, has parent div with class `claim-dependant`, then child with class `claim`. So you specify that relationship of parent class and child class to filter.

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/US7054130?oq=US7654309'
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
data = [claim.text for claim in soup.select('.claim .claim')]
print(data)
```